# How to get logged user name/Principal in Spring MVC REST channel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest, principal

I have Spring MVC REST channel:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class REST {
```

and I have my method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething")
public @ResponseBody DoSomethingResultDTO doSomething(
    @RequestBody DoSomethingRequestDTO)
```

Now I need the name of the user that is logged in. Normally I could do it by the method

```
HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()
```

but how to get it here? I have annotations for headers (`@RequestHeader`), or even cookies (`@CookieValue`). But how can I get the `Principal` in my method?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can inject Principal object to your controller handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething")
public @ResponseBody DoSomethingResultDTO doSomething(
    @RequestBody DoSomethingRequestDTO, Principal principal)
```

See [the spring reference manual for more info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

Answer (score 4):

You can also get through annotations assuming CustomUser implements UserDetails

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Entering Home Controller @AuthenticationPrincipal: " + customUser);
}

public class CustomUser implements UserDetails { // code omitted }
```